# Adding a virtual type to snowflake table without knowing the data type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In MS SQL if I add a calculated column I don't need to specify the data type as MS SQL will figure it out.

In Snowflake if I add a Virtual Column I seem to need to specify the data type:

```
ALTER TABLE ABC ADD COLUM MyVirtualCol NVARCHAR AS (col1 + 1)
```

If Col1 in a number type this will fail as Snowflake will tell me that col1 is a number type. The error message will make a suggestion as to the type it thinks I should use, which makes me think it may be able to automatically assign a type.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have Snowflake automatically assign the data type here?

Comment: Hi - what are the circumstances in which you don't know the datatype of the calculated column?

Comment: When the sql is being generated by our app. I could ask the user to supply a type, but I'd rather not ask them more than I have to, to keep the app simple.

Comment: Ok - so if you are generating the SQL then you know the datatype(s) of the column(s) being used in the calculation so you can define the datatype of the virtual column

Comment: That wouldn't be straight forward, cast(number,concat(cast(nvarchar, col1), '1')) bit of a contrived example, but the type is defined by the operations as much as by the column types, which would be a complex bit of working out.

Comment: Why not create a view instead of altering a table?  If your app creates a view dynamically, then you wouldn't need to define the data type of your calculated field...Snowflake will choose one for you.

Comment: Yes I could, I've certainly considered it and might end up going that way.

Comment: You could also consider dynamic tables in Snowflake, but those aren't GA yet, and as a calculated field, I don't think there is a benefit over a view.